# How do I save text entered in a TinyEditor box to my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, tinyeditor

I am new to asp.net. Currently working on a form that uses tinyeditor to allow a user to input data. My question is, how can I get that HTML encoded text and save it to the database (Its MSSQL) upon pressing a button?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AboutMeEdit.aspx.cs" Inherits="InteractiveCV.AdminForms.AboutMeEdit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            height: 23px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="../Scripts/tinyEditor/tiny.editor.packed.js"></script>
    <link href="../Styles/tinyeditor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Edit Your About Me in the below Text Box</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tinyeditor" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400" Height="200"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="aboutmevalidate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tinyeditor" ErrorMessage="About Me Left Empty">About Me Left Empty</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
        id: 'tinyeditor',
        width: 584,
        height: 175,`enter code here`
        cssclass: 'tinyeditor',
        controlclass: 'tinyeditor-control',
        rowclass: 'tinyeditor-header',
        dividerclass: 'tinyeditor-divider',
        controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
            'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
            'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo',        'redo', 'n',
            'font', 'size', 'style', '|', 'image', 'hr', 'link', 'unlink', '|', 'print'],
        footer: true,
        fonts: ['Verdana', 'Arial', 'Georgia', 'Trebuchet MS'],
        xhtml: true,
        cssfile: 'custom.css',
        bodyid: 'editor',
        footerclass: 'tinyeditor-footer',
        toggle: { text: 'source', activetext: 'code', cssclass: 'toggle' },
        resize: { cssclass: 'resize' }
    });
    </script>
```

I have the following Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace InteractiveCV.AdminForms
{
    public partial class AboutMeEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RIADDConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO about_me (about_me) VALUES (@about_me)", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@about_me",tinyeditor.Text);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        protected void tinyeditor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a parametrized query.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Creating the event handler for the button click? Getting the value from the text editor? Creating the DB connection? Inserting the data? Please be more specific and show where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry, thought I had actually wrote it down.I have no issues creating the dB connection. What I would like help is getting the value from the text editor and storing it in the database upon clicking the

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

Comment: I have the following Codebehind. Any Idea why Im getting tinyeditor.text does not exist in this context in the line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@about_me",tinyeditor.Text); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for TinyEditor:

```
<textarea  ID="tinyeditor" runat="server"></textarea >
```

And for your code behind, to get the text use `tinyeditor.value()`