# how to get the Tiny Editor value to code behind file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 <textarea id="tinyeditor" cols="20" rows="2" style="padding-left: 200px;" runat="server"></textarea>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var editor = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
                                id: 'tinyeditor',
                                width: 460,
                                height: 175,
                                cssclass: 'tinyeditor',
                                controlclass: 'tinyeditor-control',
                                rowclass: 'tinyeditor-header',
                                dividerclass: 'tinyeditor-divider',
                                controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
                                        'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
                                        'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'n',
                                        'font', 'size', '|', 'hr', 'link', 'unlink', '|'],
                                footer: true,
                                fonts: ['Arial', 'Courier New', 'Georgia', 'Tahoma', 'Times New Roman', 'verdana', 'Impact', 'Wing Dings'],
                                xhtml: true,
                                css: 'body{background-color:#fff}',
                                bodyid: 'editor',
                                footerclass: 'tinyeditor-footer',
                                // toggle: { text: 'source', activetext: 'wysiwyg', cssclass: 'toggle' },
                                resize: { cssclass: 'resize' }
                            });
                        </script>
```

I have Added TinyEditor to textarea , need to get the value of tinyEditor to code behind file. I have tried this, Please can any one help to solve it

Comment: Try here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020906/how-do-i-save-text-entered-in-a-tinyeditor-box-to-my-database

Comment: It is inserting Empty Data

Comment: Try adding the attribute ClientIDMode="static" to the textarea

Comment: Still It is not getting the value